# Run pureftp server as non-root user

Tags: pureftpd

I am running pureftp in docker container as non-root user `file_app`.

Here is the permission I assigned

```
chown -R file_app:file_app /etc/pure-ftpd
chown -R file_app:file_app /etc/ssl/private
chown -R file_app:file_app /var/log/pure-ftp
chown -R file_app:file_app /usr/share/lintian/overrides/pure-ftpd
chown -R file_app:file_app /usr/share/nginx # FTP HOME DIR
```

When I try to start `/usr/sbin/pure-ftpd` as user `file_app`, I get this error

> Unable to start a standalone server: Permission denied

When I start as root, everything works

How to run pure-ftpd as non-root user?

Comment: You might need to change the `Bind` line in your `/etc/pure-ftpd` to listen on a port which doesn't require root privileges, _e.g._ `Bind 127.0.0.1,2121`.

Comment: Yes!  it works after adding the parameter `--bind=0.0.0.0,2121`

Comment: Excellent.  I've added that as an answer, rather than just as a comment, if you'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change the `Bind` line in your `/etc/pure-ftpd` config file to listen on a port which doesn't require root privileges, *e.g.*:

```
Bind 127.0.0.1,2121
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also the pureftp should be compiled with `--with-nonroot` parameter